# Resampling method: `HoldValueFromLeft`, what is this?

Tags: interpolation, time-series

I came across the Resampling method: `HoldValueFromLeft`:
[image]

As this method is not explained by the official documentation, what is the meaning of it?

Also, as a counterpart of `HoldValueFromLeft`, if there is `HoldValueFromRight`? Personally, I find `HoldValueFromRight` is a more meaningful option for processing my data.

Comment: `ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", "HoldFrom" -> Right}` is noted in the documentation. So ...

Comment: Thanks @Edmund! Following your suggestion, just found it is shown as an example under `TemporalData` ...

Comment: just use this as a bookmark for the obscure option!  https://wolfram.com/xid/0n4lz2acfhe-dwbfn1